# Find first letter and first vowel in a String java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I need some help to create a function can fill an `EditText` by the first Letter and the first Vowel of another `EditText`.

Something like this:
EditText = Jhon
Output  = JO

I have this but still not working;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText Result;
    private EditText MyName;
    private EditText showResult;
    private String MyVowel;
    private String cadena, PartOne;
    private int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResult);
        MyName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NameInput);
        getInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getInfoButton);
        getInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputText = myName.getText().toString();
                String partOne= inputText.substring(0,1);

                for(int i=0;i <inputText.length();i++){
                    if((inputText.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'e')  ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'u')) {

                        System.out.println(cadena);
                    }
                }
                showResult.setText(PartOne);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: is it showing "Ju" instead? You need to break out of the loop once you find a match

Comment: You initialized the variable `Result` in `onCreate` instead of `showResult` which is required by the `onClick` method

Comment: what could be helpful  is the method split. You can split your string by a whitespace like `String[] splitted = inputText.split("\\s+");` \\s+ is for whitespace. Another possible way: `StringUtils.split(inputText);` Then you have your two Strings and you can make a substring of it.

Comment: Where are you initializing cadena in this code?? You are just printing it .. store that input text vowel character and then set it with part one in show result field

Answer (score 1):

You havn't said what your issue is. If you are stuck at the logic see the below code,

```
private String getShortForm(String inputText){
    List<Character> vowels = new ArrayList<Character>() {
        {
            add('a');
            add('e');
            add('i');
            add('o');
            add('u');
            add('A');
            add('E');
            add('I');
            add('O');
            add('U');
        }
    };
    String partOne = inputText.substring(0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < inputText.length(); i++) {
        char c = inputText.charAt(i);
        if(vowels.contains(c)){
            partOne += c;
            break;
        }
    }

    return partOne.toUpperCase();
}
```

Usage inside `onClick`,

```
Result.setText(getShortForm(inputText));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private TextView Result;
    private EditText MyName;
    private Button getInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResult);
        MyName= (EditText)findViewById(txtText);
        getInfo = (Button)findViewById(btnSpeak);
        getInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputText = MyName.getText().toString();
                String partOne= inputText.substring(0,1);
                Log.e("inputText: "+inputText, "part one: "+partOne);
                String vowels = "";
                for(int i=0;i <inputText.length();i++){
                    if((inputText.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'e') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'u') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'A') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'E') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'I') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'O') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'U')){

                        vowels = vowels+inputText.charAt(i);
                    }
                }

                Log.e("inputText: "+inputText, "vowelsFinal: "+vowels);

                String partTwo = vowels.substring(0,1);
                Log.e("inputText: "+inputText, "partTwo: "+partTwo);

                String finalString = partOne+partTwo;
                Log.e("inputText: "+inputText, "finalString: "+finalString);

                Result.setText(finalString);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: If your problem is solved then just click on the (✓check) mark.